# Why quantificators don't pass through xargs

Tags: bash, shell, xargs

The problem I faced with is that wildcard quantificator doesn't pass through xargs to command for some reason.

Assume, that we have file ***file1*** with such content:

```
-l
-a
f*
```

we need to pass arguments to *ls* via *xargs*.

```
cat file1 | xargs -n3 ls
```

The output equivalent to *ls -la* command, with additon from terminal, that

```
ls: cannot access f*: No such file or directory.
```

But the file is in directory (`ls -la f*` returns suitable output)
If we substitute f* to *file1* for example, we'll have right output too.

Can you explain me, why does it happen? Thanks.

### EDIT1:

It seems interesting to add, how we can pass arguments from file `file1` through shell interpreter to `ls` command. Below is the example:

```
ls `xargs -n3 < file1`
```

Now shell expansion is made before `ls` invocation resulting in same output as for `ls -la f*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `f*` expression is also known as a shell glob, and is supposed to be interpreted by the shell.  You can try it out independently *e.g.* by running `echo f*`.

When you run `ls -la f*` from the shell, the shell interprets it according to your directory contents, and calls `ls` with the expanded version, like: `ls -la file1 file2 file3`.  You can get some commands confused about this if it matches no file and the command expects one.

But when you pass that argument to `ls` through `xargs`, the shell doesn't get a chance to expand it, and `ls` feels like it's invoked exactly as `ls -la f*`.  It recognizes `-la` as options, and `f*` as a filename to list.  That file happens not to exist, so it fails with the error message you see.

You could get it to fail on a more usual filename:

```
$ ls non_existing_file
ls: cannot access non_existing_file: No such file or directory.
```

Or you could get it to succeed by actually having a file of that name:

```
$ touch 'f*'
$ xargs ls -la <<< 'f*'
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jb jb 0 2013-11-13 23:08 f*
$ rm 'f*'
```

Notice how I had to use single quotes so that the shell would *not* interpret `f*` as a glob when creating and deleting it.

Unfortuately, you can't get it to expand it when it gets passed directly from `xargs` to `ls`, since there's no shell there.

Answer (score 2):

The contents of `file` are passed to `xargs` via standard input, so the shell never sees them to process the glob. `xargs` then passes them to `ls`, again without the shell ever seeing them, so `f*` is treated as a literal 2-character file name.